# Variable Mismatch with case

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having difficulty with a java problem I am attempting to make,
I am very new and still learning  if anyone can spot what I am doing wrong I would appreciate any help.

I am attempting to have the user type in a year from 2000 to 2016 and the output would be the players statistics.

Thank You

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NflPlayers{

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Year (2000-2016): " );
        String year = input.next();
        input.close();

        if (yearNumber(year) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Year 2000-2016");
            System.out.println("Invalid year input.");
            System.exit(0);
    }

        System.out.println(year + " Passing touchdowns");
    }


         int getNumberOfPasses(int year) {

                switch (yearNumber(null)) {

                    case 1: return 28;
                    case 2: return 36;
                    case 3: return 33;
                    case 4: return 25;
                    case 5: return 34;
                    case 6: return 39;
                    case 7: return 36;
                    case 8: return 28;
                    case 9: return 0;
                    case 10: return 50;
                    case 11: return 24;
                    case 12: return 26;
                    case 13: return 28;
                    case 14: return 23;
                    case 15: return 28;
                    case 16: return 18;
                    case 17: return 0;
                        default: return 0;

                }
    }

        public static int yearNumber(String year) {

            int yearNumber;

            switch (year){
            case"2016":
                yearNumber = 1;
                break;

            case"2015":
                yearNumber = 2;
                break;

            case"2014":
                yearNumber = 3;
                break;

            case"2013":
                yearNumber = 4;
                break;

            case"2012":
                yearNumber = 5;
                break;

            case"2011":
                yearNumber = 6;
                break;

            case"2010":
                yearNumber = 7;
                break;

            case"2009":
                yearNumber = 8;
                break;

            case"2008":
                yearNumber = 9;
                break;

            case"2007":
                yearNumber = 10;
                break;

            case"2006":
                yearNumber = 11;
                break;

            case"2005":
                yearNumber = 12;
                break;

            case"2004":
                yearNumber = 13;
                break;

            case"2003":
                yearNumber = 14;
                break;

            case"2002":
                yearNumber = 15;
                break;

            case"2001":
                yearNumber = 16;
                break;

            case"2000":
                yearNumber = 17;
                break;

            default:
                yearNumber = 0;
                break;

            }

            return yearNumber;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca use `do{}while()` loop instead for example :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String year;
boolean pass = false;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a Year (2000-2016): ");
    year = input.next();
    try {
        if (Integer.parseInt(year) >= 2000 && Integer.parseInt(year) <= 2006) {
            System.out.println("true");
            pass = true;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Not correct try again");
    }
} while (!pass);
```

---

So if the user enter a year between 2000 and 2006 you can pass, else repeat again until the user enter the correct year.

Comment: did you try it @MehrajMalik :)

Comment: Hello Thank you for your feedback it works, and much simpler than the mess i was trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and examined it.

It appears you've left out a method call for `getNumberOfPasses()`, which is the main problem I can tell.

with `System.out.println(year + " Passing touchdowns");` you don't actually want the `year` displayed, i believe the correct code you're looking for is:

```
    System.out.println(getNumberOfPasses(yearNumber(year)) + " Passing touchdowns");
```

This will run through both methods to display the info you need. However, you will need to fix the method header of `int getNumberOfPasses(int year)` to `static int getNumberOfPasses(int year)`

Furthermore, you could eliminate one of the methods entirely and just have the return values for passes tied to the year you input. Rather than passing digits from 1-17 to another method.

Hope this helps and good luck with your projects!

Comment: Thank You very much Devlin, I appreciate your feedback.